# Which JavaScript libraries will handle popout windows (i.e. like Meebo or Gmail chat windows)?

Tags: javascript

I could write this, but before I do, I wanted to check to see if there are existing solutions out there since it seems a lot of websites already do this, so I was wondering if there was a quick way to do this.

Also, I am talking about "popout" windows, not "popup" windows.  All JavaScript libraries support "popup" windows, but I want ones where they originally open as "popup" windows in the same browser window, but there is also a link to open them up in a brand new browser window.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Cappuccino, it's more of a windowing framework than a web 2.0 framework. It's based off of Apples Cocoa, and uses a Superset of Javascript called Objective-J. Superset meaning that any JS is valid, but it extends on the language with additional syntax that is similar to Cocoa and Objetive-C.

http://cappuccino.org

Answer (score 1):

```
var oDiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
var oWindow = window.open("about:blank");

oWindow.document.body.appendChild(oDiv.cloneNode(true))
```

You will probably also need to move stylesheets there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don"t know a framework to do that for you. But the JS code to do that might be simple.

For the in-page-popup part, just open an absolute div. If you want the div to become a real popup, open a popup window then remove your div content from the main document and append it to the popup window document (you way have to clone it because JS may not like passing around DOM nodes between different documents).

Answer (score 0):

JQuery - Look for Dialog.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog

You can customize with CSS to control the title bar, if it can be moved or resized, etc.

PS: Follow the link for an example.

Answer (score 0):

you can try http://mochaui.com/demo/, it's written in mootools